# How to send custom http response code back from spring cloud functions when running as standalone app?

Tags: spring, cloud

There doesn't appear to be a way to set a custom HTTP response code when running a spring cloud function as a standalone app. There doesn't appear to be anything in the docs either.

I have tried creating a new generic message and adding a statusCode response header, but that has had no effect, a 200 response is always sent. I am guessing that I might be able to throw ErrorResponseException in order to get an error status code through, but there should be a way to set non-error status codes.

`        GenericMessage response = null;

```
    responseHeaders.put("statusCode", this.httpStatus.value());


    MessageHeaders responseMessageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(responseHeaders);
    response = new GenericMessage<Object>(payload,responseMessageHeaders);

    return response;`
```